# BackboneJS - Displaying external templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm having some problems with displaying external templates. So far I have main.js file, an index.html file, a header_content.html file (with some simple html code), a header.js view-file and a tpl.js file.

my index.html is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Backbone project</title> 
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/style.less">
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/admin.less">
<script data-main="js/config" src="js/libs/require.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

next, there is the main.js file:

```
require([
'jquery',
'lodash',
'backbone',
'utils/tpl',
'views/header'
 ],

 function($, _, Backbone, HeaderMenuView, tpl) {

IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
       this.el.html(); // is this right?
    }
});

var index_view = new IndexView({el:'#container'});

tpl.loadTemplates(['header'], function() {
    window.app = new IndexView({el:'#container'});
    Backbone.history.start();
});

});
```

and then I have the header.js view file:

```
define(
['jquery', 'lodash', 'backbone', 'utils/tpl'],

function($, _, Backbone, tpl) {

var HeaderMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('header_content'));
    },

    render: function(eventName) {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this.el;
    },

});

return HeaderMenuView;

});
```

and as last file, I have the tpl.js file, which looks like this:

```
define(
['jquery', 'lodash', 'backbone'],

function($, _, Backbone) {

var tpl = {

    templates: {},

    loadTemplates: function(names, callback) {

        var that = this;

        var loadTemplate = function(index) {
                var name = names[index];
                console.log('Loading template: ' + name);
                $.get('templates/' + name + '.html', function(data) {
                    that.templates[name] = data;
                    index++;
                    if (index < names.length) {
                        loadTemplate(index);
                    } else {
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            };

        loadTemplate(0);
    },

    get: function(name) {
        return this.templates[name];
    }

};

return tpl;

});
```

when I'm running this, I get several script error's :-/
All I want is the header_content.html template to be displayed in the #container Div.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what kinds of error you are getting?

Comment: @YuruiRayZhang Hmm, i'm getting several errors, i think there is something wrong in general with my code. Especially the main.js file seems to cause the most problems. I get fexample "Error: Script error" rooted in requirejs, "Error: Load timeout for modules: backbone", also rootes in requirejs..., sometimes i get "tpl is undefined" etc etc... whew :-/

Comment: Hm...I dont know too much about requirejs. But make sure you got the correct configuration for the load path of backbonejs. also, make sure underscore.js is loaded before backbone.js.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've included a `require.config()` call, so you'll probably need to set one up. Otherwise, require doesn't know where to look for Backbone, jQuery and the like. You want to do this before your first `require()` call in main.js.

You'll want something like this:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '.',
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery.min',
        'underscore': '../lib/underscore.min',
        'backbone': '../lib/backbone.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        }
    }
});
```

The `shim` section handles the fact that Backbone and Underscore don't use `define()` to define themselves and declare their dependencies.

You can read more about the Configuration Options [**here**](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).

Hope this helps.